# Create a "wrapped" ndarray from a given array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to create a 2D array from an array by using a rolled given array as the rows of the 2D array of a specified row dimension. For example:

```
r = np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

want a matrix of 3 rows (using r) as

```
[[2,3,4,1],
 [1,2,3,4],
 [4,1,2,3]]
```

I think I have an idea by defining a function using numpy.roll and a for-loop but I'm trying to avoid that as my 2D array is going to be very large. I would like to have the ability to roll backwards if possible.

Is there a way using numpy functions that can do this instead? Any suggestions on this are appreciated.

Comment: you can try `random.shuffle`

Comment: Well I should mention that it should have some order to it.  If the desired matrix has n rows, then the sequence of rolls must be from -1, 0, ... , n-1 not including n-1.

Comment: can't you do this with a circular convolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/) is an option, you can use [`scipy.linalg.circulant`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.circulant.html).  You will still have to tweak the argument to `circulant` to get exactly what you want, since `circulant` simply makes the given one-dimensional argument the first column of a square [circulant matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix).

For example:

```
In [25]: from scipy.linalg import circulant

In [26]: r = np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

Here's what `circulant` gives:

```
In [27]: circulant(r)
Out[27]: 
array([[1, 4, 3, 2],
       [2, 1, 4, 3],
       [3, 2, 1, 4],
       [4, 3, 2, 1]])
```

With some help from `np.roll()`, you can get your desired array:

```
In [28]: circulant(np.roll(r, -1)).T[:-1]
Out[28]: 
array([[2, 3, 4, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 1, 2, 3]])
```

Or:

```
In [29]: circulant(np.roll(r[::-1], -1))[1:]
Out[29]: 
array([[2, 3, 4, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 1, 2, 3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is *a* solution to the problem. It uses numpy's vstack to combine the rows into an array. It is maybe not the most efficient one though (I don't know the efficiency of `res = np.vstack((res, r))` )

```
import numpy as np

def main():
    r = np.array([1,2,3,4])
    x = [i for i in range(1, len(r))] + [0]           # Forwards
    # x = [len(r)-1] + [i for i in range(len(r)-1)]     # Backwards
    r = r[x]
    res = r
    for c in range(2):
        r = r[x]
        res = np.vstack((res, r))
    print res
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It produces:

```
[[2 3 4 1]     'Forwards'
 [3 4 1 2]
 [4 1 2 3]]

[[4 1 2 3]     'Backwards'
 [3 4 1 2]
 [2 3 4 1]]
```

To change the order, it's only necessary to change the `x =` line.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using list indexing.

```
r = [1, 2, 3, 4] # note: a list, so we can easily concatenate
result = np.array([r[i:] + r[:i] for i in range(1, len(r))])

array([[2, 3, 4, 1],
       [3, 4, 1, 2],
       [4, 1, 2, 3]])
```

This is pretty flexible because the indexing is still meaningful for negative values of `i`. So you just have to mess around with `range` to get the desired start and stop rows, and direction.

In particular, to get the exact result you wanted:

```
np.array([r[i:] + r[:i] for i in range(1, -len(r) + 2, -1)])

array([[2, 3, 4, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 1, 2, 3]])
```